# Ajax Calling Both Success and Failure

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ok, so this is a weird one. My Ajax call seems to be calling both success and failure at the same time. When I send my Ajax call, it will post to the database, but then also throw the error message. So the Ajax call is working -- just with an error message. When I inspected the problem with Fiddler the request posted as 200 (success).

The code is pretty simple:

```
var myDataObject = new Object();
myDataObject.one = $('#SomeTextBoxId').val;
myDataObject.two = $('#SomeOtherTextBoxId').val          

// NOTE: AJAX is calling success and fail
SendAjax("/ServiceHandlers/SomeHandler?HandlerName", myDataObject, function() { alert("SUCCESS!");}, function() {alert("FAILURE?");});
```

Here is the `SendAjax` function:

```
function SendAjax(postUrl, postData, successFunction, failureFunction)
{
  /*
     postUrl:           The URL to which the request will be posted
     postData:          The JSON encoded input to be posted to the postUrl
     successFunction:   The function to be executed on a successful post
     failureFunction:   The function to be executed on a failed post
   */

// Stringify the postData
postData = JSON.stringify(postData);

$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: postUrl,
    data: postData,
    success: function (data, status, xhr)
    {
        successFunction(data, status, xhr);
    },
    error: function (xhr, status, error)
    {
        failureFunction(xhr, status, error);
    }
});
}
```

Any suggestions?

EDIT - Fixed function in Ajax call, still no luck.

Comment: Does your code read `function { alert("SUCCESS!");}` or `function() { alert("SUCCESS!");}`? Those brackets are important.

Comment: BTW, what Ajax framework is that? looks nice and simple.

Comment: @Gareth sorry, it reads function() { alert("SUCCESS!");}

Comment: maybe it is status code 200: BAD RESPONSE. would be the only imaginable way for me to get a success(200) and an Error (BAD RESPONSE) in one instant

Comment: Fixed the problem. I had a parameter passing in and the same parameter hardcoded, so I just through off the Ajax. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The thing is the way you are sending the functions as parameters is wrong.

When you "send" `alert("SUCCESS!")` as a parameter, you are NOT sending it, you are calling it.

Instead, you need create a container function on the go. Just like this:

```
// You can make it a single line if you want,
// I'm was just trying to separate it to look more clear
SendAjax(
    "/ServiceHandlers/SomeHandler?HandlerName",
    myDataObject, 
    function() { alert("SUCCESS!") },
    function() { alert("FAILURE?") }
);
```

Comment: Yes, sorry, perhaps that was a bad example. Even when I pass it in as a function, success and failure are called. The Ajax posts then the failure message pops up for half a second.

Answer (score 0):

You're calling the alerts. You're not passing them in by reference. It should look like

```
SendAjax("/ServiceHandlers/SomeHandler?HandlerName", myDataObject, 
    function() {
      alert("SUCCESS!") 
    },
    function() { 
      alert("FAILURE?") 
    });
```

It's trying to pass the return value of alert. Rather than the actual function itself.

Comment: Yes, sorry, perhaps that was a bad example. Even when I pass it in as a function, success and failure are called. The Ajax posts then the failure message pops up for half a second.